# Setting tick labels in mpld3

Tags: python, matplotlib, mpld3

I'm trying to create a simple bar graph with some data (hard coded here, but I'll be reading it in from a file at some point). So far, I'm able to get the bar graph, but I would like the attribute "Feature Name" to come under each bar. Right now, I'm only getting numbers 1 through 16. What can I do to make each feature under each bar?

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpld3

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

N = 17
feature_name = ('AccountLength','Intlact','Vmailact','Vmailnumber','day minutes','day calls','day charge','evening minutes','evening calls','evening charge','night minutes','night calls','night charge','intl minutes','intl calls','intl charge','cust calls')
importance = (0.0304,0.0835,0.0222,0.0301,0.1434,0.0315,0.1354,0.0677,0.0268,0.0669,0.0386,0.0286,0.0371,0.0417,0.0521,0.0434,0.1197)
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.20
rects = ax.bar(ind, importance, width, color = 'r')
ax.grid(color='white', linestyle='solid')

ax.set_title("Why are my customers churning?", size=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Importance in percentage')
ax.set_xlabel('Feature Name')
ax.set_xticklabels( (feature_name) )
labels = (feature_name)
tooltip = mpld3.plugins.PointLabelTooltip(rects, labels=labels)
mpld3.plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)

mpld3.show()
```

Edit: turns out that if I use plt.show(), I can see ticklabels, but when I try to do the same in mpld3, it doesn't work. Also wondering why the tooltip doesn't show up.

Comment: What version of `mpld3` are you using?  Can you try using the most [recent version from github](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3)?

Comment: I'm using the most recent one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is too late, however maybe this could help someone else.

Setting the text as tick labels seems really have some issues in *mpld3* package, however I was able to do this when plotting some data to certain range values, then setting ticks to this range and finally setting tick labels to needed ones.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpld3

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

feature_name = ('AccountLength','Intlact','Vmailact','Vmailnumber','day minutes','day calls','day charge','evening minutes','evening calls','evening charge','night minutes','night calls','night charge','intl minutes','intl calls','intl charge','cust calls')
importance = (0.0304,0.0835,0.0222,0.0301,0.1434,0.0315,0.1354,0.0677,0.0268,0.0669,0.0386,0.0286,0.0371,0.0417,0.0521,0.0434,0.1197)
ind = range(1, len(feature_name)+1)
width = 0.20

rects = ax.bar(ind, importance, width, color = 'r')

ax.grid(linestyle='solid')
ax.set_title("Why are my customers churning?", size=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Importance in percentage')
ax.set_xlabel('Feature Name')
ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_xticklabels(feature_name)

mpld3.show()
```

Result:

[image: mpld3 ticklabels example]

There is an extra staff to do with ticks rotation (also not supported in *mpld3*). Maybe custom plugin could be written to achieve this. If someone need this, I will update answer.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into my notebook, and am getting numbers not text in the X axis. I am using mpld3 0.5.2. I am wondering what is different about your set up to get the text labels.

Answer (score 0):

Setting tick labels and locations is not supported in mpld3. See [issue 22](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/issues/22).

Tooltips do not appear because `PointLabelTooltip()` function accepts matplotlib Collection or Line2D object as an input, while `plt.bar()` returns BarContainer object.

UPD: Tick labels were tested with version 0.2 & 0.3git.